# i have tried to make menuicon functional but it is not working how can i do it

Tags: reactjs, forms, menu, react-hooks

I am trying to make the menuIcon funtional in react js. I am trying to make it like when I click it the menu will open with login options in mobile view and when I click the menu again it will close like a hamburger menu. I have tried the below code and its not working i want it in reactjs functional based working code. I am new to reactjs pls help.

The code is as below:

```
import React,{ useState }from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import logo from './images/logo.png'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'

function Navbar() {
    
   const[openMenu,setOpenMenu] = useState();

   const handleClick = () => {
        setOpenMenu(true);
    }

   const handleClose = () => {
        setOpenMenu(false);
    }

    return (
      
        <div className="navbar">
            <Link to="/" className="header__link">
            <img
            className="header__logo"
            src={logo}
            alt="logo"
            />
            </Link>
        <div className="header__nav">
            <form7 onSubmit={formSubmit}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email"  name="name" value={data.name} onChange={InputEvent}/>
           <input type="password" placeholder="Password"  name="password" value={data.password} onChange={InputEvent}/>
           <button  className="button__nav"  onClick={() => history.push('/myvehicles')}>Log In</button> 
          <MenuIcon fontSize="large" color="primary"  open={handleClick} onClose={handleClose}/>
            </form7>
            </div>
    </div>   
)
```

}
export default Navbar

Comment: Try to go through the documentation of `Menu` here - https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#material-icons/. B'coz the `open` and `onClose` seems not be valid prop for the component. And also see if this `Drawer` component fits your case - https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/

Comment: then what props should i use to when to open and close the menu icon having one child in it.

Comment: @H S i also tried to put material ui drawers also but due to class constructors it made other components replace the position alot.